# JSON Path PostProcessor: storing JSON arrays and objects loses their data type

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonpath

I'm using JSON Path PostProcessor with path expressions to store a JSON object from a JSON response, but when I later retrieve the variable, it has been reduced to string with key - pair values. So I don't know that was a string or number.

Example:
Response looks like this

```
{
.
.
"currency" : {
                "code" : "AUD",
                "name" : "Australian Dollars",
                "symbol" : "$"
            },
.
}
```

Using the path expression, I find `currency` and save it.
However, when I use it in a HTTP Request body data (`"currency" : ${currency},`), 
it comes like this:

```
"currency" : {code=AUD, name=Australian Dollars, symbol=$},
```

How do I get the JSON Path PostProcessor to save the JSON object 'as is" without losing the data type details? Should I be using a different approach instead of JSON Path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend switching to [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language, this way you will have full control of what is going on and be able to do what you want.

Assuming you have the following JSON response:

```
{
  "currency": {
    "code": "AUD",
    "name": "Australian Dollars",
    "symbol": "$"
  }
}
```

the relevant Groovy coode will be something like:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData())
def currency = json.currency
def currencyString = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(currency).toPrettyString()
vars.put('currency', currencyString)
log.info(currencyString)
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy JSON]

References:

- [Groovy - Learn](http://groovy-lang.org/learn.html)
- Groovy - [Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: This is just what I need. Thanks for the references too!